# Projections not being applied after upgrading to Spring Boot 2.5.4

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate

For some reason, Projections are not being applied any longer after upgrading to Spring Boot 2.5.4.  I really can't figure out why.

I have a class `WhoDidWhatWhen` (I've changed the class / variable names in the example):

```java
@Entity
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class WhoDidWhatWhen {

  @Id
  private Long id;

  @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
  private User who;

  @NotNull private String what;

  @NotNull @PastOrPresent private Date when;
}
```

and I have a projection in the same package as the above class:

```java
@Projection(
    name = "whoDidWhatWhenProjection",
    types = {WhoDidWhatWhen.class})
public interface WhoDidWhatWhenProjection {
  @Value("#{target.id}")
  long getId();

  User getWho();

  String getWhat();

  Date getWhen();
}
```

and finally I have my RestRepository:

```java
@RepositoryRestResource(exported = false, excerptProjection = WhoDidWhatWhenProjection.class)
public interface WhoDidWhatWhenRepository
    extends PagingAndSortingRepository<WhoDidWhatWhen, Long>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<WhoDidWhatWhen> {}
```

For some reason the projection / excerpt just isn't being picked up and applied and I just can't figure out why.

I even tried to manually register to projection, but to not avail:

```java
@Configuration
public class RestConfiguration implements RepositoryRestConfigurer {
  public void configureRepositoryRestConfiguration(RepositoryRestConfiguration config) {
    config.getProjectionConfiguration().addProjection(WhoDidWhatWhenProjection.class);
  }
}
```

Has anyone experienced this before?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know an answer to your particular problem, but I would like to offer you an alternative, which is [Blaze-Persistence Entity Views](https://github.com/Blazebit/blaze-persistence#entity-view-usage). You can imagine this to be like Spring Data Projections on steroids, with mappings that affect the SQL and thus improve performance. Mappings are fully type validated to avoid runtime surprises and the integration is seamless.

I created the library to allow easy mapping between JPA models and custom interface or abstract class defined models, something like Spring Data Projections on steroids. The idea is that you define your target structure(domain model) the way you like and map attributes(getters) via JPQL expressions to the entity model.

A DTO model for your use case could look like the following with Blaze-Persistence Entity-Views:

```
@EntityView(WhoDidWhatWhen.class)
public interface WhoDidWhatWhenProjection {
    @IdMapping
    Long getId();
    String getWhat();
    Date getWhen();
    UserDto getWho();

    @EntityView(User.class)
    interface UserDto {
        @IdMapping
        Long getId();
        String getName();
    }
}
```

Querying is a matter of applying the entity view to a query, the simplest being just a query by id.

`WhoDidWhatWhenProjection a = entityViewManager.find(entityManager, WhoDidWhatWhenProjection.class, id);`

The Spring Data integration allows you to use it almost like Spring Data Projections: https://persistence.blazebit.com/documentation/entity-view/manual/en_US/index.html#spring-data-features

```
Page<WhoDidWhatWhenProjection> findAll(Pageable pageable);
```

The best part is, it will only fetch the state that is actually necessary!